# How to set up custom mappings for a specific keyboard

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I bought a [Razr Tartarus](http://www.razerzone.com/au-en/gaming-keyboards-keypads/razer-tartarus), which is a comfortable keypad, perceived by Ubuntu as a regular keyboard. I would like to use it as an extension of my regular keyboard, in order to have convenient extra keys to map to Gnome and application shortcuts.

In order to extend the potentiality of my main keyboard without conflicting with it, it would be ideal to have a custom mapping, only specific to my keypad. For example, if i mapped it to a Greek keyboard with letters α, β, γ, δ etcetera, i would have more symbols to map to shortcuts in Gnome and in all my applications, without any conflict with existing shortcuts on my regular keyboard.

I think that this is interesting in general, one might even want to have two keyboards, one for typing and one all for accelerators. Unfortunately as far as i could see, changing the keyboard mapping applies to *all* connected keyboards, and it is not possible do chose a specific mapping for a specific keyboard